# Complexity of calculating the determinant

Tags: matrices, algorithms, determinant, computational-complexity

For calculating the determinant, there are several algorithms available:

- Laplace: $\mathcal{O}{(n!)}$
- Bareiss: $\mathcal{O}{(n^3)}$
- LU-decomposition: $\mathcal{O}{(n^3)}$
- Strassen: $\mathcal{O}{(n^{2.807})}$
- Coppersmith-Winograd: $\mathcal{O}{(n^{2.376})}$

Now my question is: What is the theoretical limit for calculating the determinant. It is $\mathcal{O}{(n^2)}$, isn't it? If yes, how is this possible?

Is this still an active research field, or is the Coppersmith-Winograd-Algorithm "the limit"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That algorithm's Wikipedia page mentions slight improvements for matrix multiplication, which has the same complexity as determinant calculation. The best is due to Le Gall 2014, reducing the exponent to $2.3728639$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but what is the theoretical limit?

Comment: @chrysaetos99 $O(n^\omega)$ for some unknown $\omega\ge2$, although $O(n^2\ln n)$ can be obtained as a lower limit [in an important special case](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S0097539702402147).